# Make Most Columns None If Condition in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nonetype

I have a pandas dataframe with one boolean column. I want to set most of the columns to "None" if the boolean is False. I don't want to change the object that I am iterating over, but what is an elegant way to do this?

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `apply` function to iterate over the rows:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.DataFrame(
   {"a": list(range(10)), 
    "b": list(range(10)), 
    "c": [random.choice((True, False)) for _ in range(10)]
})

def mask(row):
   if row["c"]:
      row["a"] = None
   return row

df.apply(mask, axis=1)
```

Yields the following result:

```
   a    b      c
0  0  0.0  False
1  1  1.0  False
2  2  NaN   True
3  3  3.0  False
4  4  NaN   True
5  5  NaN   True
6  6  NaN   True
7  7  NaN   True
8  8  NaN   True
9  9  NaN   True
```

Meanwhile the original dataframe is unchanged.

This is certainly not the fastest method, but its very flexible. If speed is an important factor you might also consider the `where` method.

```
cols_to_replace = ["a", "b"]
new_col_names = ["new_" + col for col in cols_to_replace]
df[new_col_names] = df[cols_to_replace].where(df["c"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
df['result'] = np.where(df['boolean col'] == False, np.nan, 'Not Null')
```